# Mathsf Greek Symbols Lualatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

I am using Lualatex with Latin Modern as math font. I want to produce mathsf greek symbols. However, it seems that it doesn't work for greek symbols (Using `\setmathfont[\range=mathsf]{Latin Modern Math}`). In regular pdflatex `\mathsf{\greekletter}` produces an sans serif greek symbol. So I wonder, is this also possible in lualatex? Preferably the same font as regular pdflatex (I think it's CM).

Kind Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I can see, there is no sans serif mathematical Gamma in Unicode, just the bold version. `:(`

Answer (score 6):

For reasons that I find very mysterious, Unicode has the full range of Greek in sans serif bold, upright and italic, but it doesn't cover sans serif Greek in medium weight; to wit, there are

```
MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL GAMMA (U+1D758)
MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL GAMMA (U+1D792)
```

and the other Greek letters (upper and lower case), but no medium weight ones.

So it's not surprising that `\symsf{\Gamma}` (or `\mathsf{\Gamma}` in an older version of `unicode-math`) gives no different symbol: there's none that satisfies the request.

You can get through with `\textsf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$\Gamma\ne\textsf{\upshape Γ}\ne\symbfsf{\Gamma}$

$Γ\ne\textsf{\upshape Γ}\ne\symbfsf{Γ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A kludge, I know, but I can't offer any better. Of course the sans serif font defined in the document should support Greek.

Comment: the unicode technical committee has a somewhat misguided fixation that symbols need to be assigned in nicely defined blocks, and they therefore assigned a single 2(hex)k block to the math alphanumerics.  i'm not really sure how they managed to decide to omit the lightface sans greek (i'm pretty sure i was there when they did it!), but i'm doing the best i can to get the omission reversed.  (i've provided documentation citing nist on the international system of units; if anyone has better documentation than that, please let me know.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton What is the current status of this? I too would very much like to use medium weight sans serif italic Greek symbols, mainly because in physics there are certain tensors denoted by Greek letters (e.g. permittivity, Levi-Civita, etc.) and their existing symbols don't comply with ISO 80000-2 recommendations.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL -- I'm now retired, and my connections to the UTC members with whom I worked are rather tenuous.  But I'll try to re-establish contact and check.  (It would be a good idea to remind me; I'll add a note to my to-do list, with reference to this question, but email to me at bnb at tug.org wouldn't hurt.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you.